# Terminate function without "Variable not assigned error"?

Tags: matlab, function, return, exit, break

There have been some similar questions posed here but none seem to answer my following question. I have a function with a menu inside the function. This function is embedded within a main function. If the user hits "Quit" on the menu gui, I want the function to stop on that line and not continue AND I want the main function to stop as well.

But the function also has variable outputs, so I always get the error: "Output arguments {var} not assigned during call to {function}"

I have tried using "return", "break" or others, but have not seen a simple solution to this problem. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
function main
   %do stuff
   function [a,b,c,d]=sub_main
      imenu=menu(' ','yes','no','quit');
      if imenu==3
         %RETURN, BREAK OR SOMETHING!
      end
      a=1;  b=2;  c=3;  d=4;
   end
end
```

Comment: Set dummy variables within your `if` statement, just before the `break`, i.e. `a=nan;` etc.

Comment: Yea, I thought about doing that, but it doesn't seem very elegant. I just thought there might be an easier way